# Only Enlightened badges are awarded?

Tags: support, badges, enlightened-badge

Today I noticed that almost all awarded badges visible in the Recent Badges list are Enlightened badges:

[image: Badge]

How is this possible? Were other users unable to get any other badges during this time? Do I perhaps not understand something about the Recent Badges list?

Comment: Missing about something to understand don't lead down vote :( .I unable to find any thing in search.

Comment: I think it's the language barrier. The hard statement which you made in the title "Other badges are dead" is completely untrue. Try to ask a question about the observation instead of making a hard statement based on an ungrounded assumption, e.g. "Why do I see only [enlightenend] in list of recent badges and not other badges?", along with the [support] tag instead of [discussion].

Comment: @Chichiray Thanks for suggestion I care about this for next question.

Comment: In the age of Aquarius, we should all be enlightened by now.

Comment: In Meta people are VERY easy on the downvote arrow don't take it hard. In this specific case guess the downvotes are from those thinking it's trivial knowledge.

Comment: @Sha Thanks for nice comment . +1 :0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Badges are awarded in batches. You simply see the result of a batch focused on `Enlightened` badges.

Wait a while for another batch process to award a different set of badges. I see `Notable Question` is currently being handed out, for example.