# When are badge calculations done?

Tags: discussion, badges

I'm just curious about when certain badge calculations are done.  Are certain badges like the serial upvote detection script that runs at 3am?

I have this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/17241902/2502012.  I DO have nice answer for it, but I dont have enlightened yet.  Not sure if that is because they are calculated differently or what.

Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: If you monitor the Recently Awarded section on the right of the main page, you will notice badges are awarded throughout the day. I'm also pretty sure some of them, including `Enlightened`, are not awarded on a fixed time basis.

Comment: Related: [Only Enlightened badges are awarded?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172359)

Comment: The "Enlightened" script seems to run every few hours. But you got that 10th vote only 35 minutes ago.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, is there a meta question that explains when each badge is calculated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Badges are handed out in batches throughout the day, different batch jobs handle different badge types.

It can take up to a few hours for the next Enlightened badge to be awarded. There is no overview of when what batch runs exactly, you'll just have to be patient.

Comment: So there is no information all in one place of what runs when?

Comment: That information is probably available to the developers, but I am not aware of that information being public.